# How do I add an image on my computer to a folder while using terminal?

Tags: command-line

Hi I'm learning how to use terminal and I've created and image folder through terminal and now I'm wondering how I add an image that I already have saved on my computer by using terminal. I'm wondering if I can add an image to the folder without having to go through finder...

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: use the move (mv) or copy (cp) command: cp [sourcePath]/[fileName] [targetPath]

Answer (score 0):

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/cp.1.html explains the *cp* command and http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/mv.1.html illustrates the *mv* command. Both work within the terminal.

Let's take an example, copying a file from a folder named /images to a folder named /home/you/Pictures where the image file is named koala.jpg and your username in Ubuntu is you .

```
cp /images/koala.jpg /home/you/Pictures
```

Please note that Linux, and Ubuntu, are case sensitive when it comes to file and directory names: **Pictures** and **pictures** are two different directories.

Also, if you are accustomed to Windows, please note where Windows would use a backstroke \ in a directory path, Linux uses /